# Richfaces fileupload UI look and feel

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I am using richfaces, in our project and there is a fileupload component in richfaces. I want to change the UI of component. Like, one InputText box followed with browse button followed by upload button.

There is any way of getting the change of fileupload UI using xcss file?

Comment: I won't post an answer for this, so here's just a hint: try to achieve the same in **plain vanilla** HTML/CSS/JS. If that's not possible, then it's not possible in JSF at all.

Answer (score 0):

Styling file upload element is not an easy task, using common CSS techniques doesn't work, but sister Google found a solution. Try this page, it should help you as well:

http://www.burhankhan.com/css_tricks/styling-file-upload-input-box-in-css/